# Finding distinct count in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a column in my PRODUCTS table called categories. Users can add more than one category per a record, and each category is coma seperated. I need to do a find for distinct categories within the PRODUCTS table.

Comment: Why do you not have a `ProductCategory` model that links products with their categories? This would make counting far easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree a table with each product's categories would offer much easier solutions.  But, here's my understanding of your question,

```
Product.where("categories is like :pattern", :pattern => "%#{category_name}%")
```

Comment: When I tried this, this is the output i got for count: #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000102454fb8>

Comment: This works for me: products.find(:all, :select => "DISTINCT(categories)").size however its not counting each individual comma separated category.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mitch, you should have a `ProductCategory` table. But just to answer your question try something like this:

```
Product.find(:all, :select => "distinct(categories)").map { |c| c.category }.uniq
```